Preventing window from jumping when clicking on a link in MapLibre GL JS
I have an interactive map, entirely based on Mapbox's tutorials. I use the example of the store locator, coupled with the one on clusters. In addition to this, TomazicM helped me a lot to set up a filter system.
On all the examples, I encounter a problem. It is easily reproduced in the following example.
If you have fun clicking several times on the links in the list on the left, at some point the page will jump, i.e. when you click you will go to the top of the page, and sometimes to the bottom.
After several tests, I noticed the createPopUp() function, and I noticed that if I just put <h3>${name}</h3><h4>${region}</h4>, the page doesn't jump anymore.. On the other hand, I lose the automatic opening of popus when clicking on links.
if I put back: <h3>${currentFeature.properties.name}</h3><h4>${currentFeature.properties.region}</h4> The page jumps again.
If I add an e.preventDefault in the click, the page no longer jumps, but again I lose the popup's openness.
link.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        for (const feature of stores.features) {
if (this.id === 'link-${feature.properties.id}') {
            flyToStore(feature);
            e.preventDefault();
            createPopUp(feature);
}
        }

Does anyone have a solution ? Or maybe the problem comes from somewhere else?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Add a raster image to a map layer</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@3.6.2/dist/maplibre-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@3.6.2/dist/maplibre-gl.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@7/turf.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    html, body, #map { height: 100%; }
    .sidebar {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width:25%;
      background:white;
    }
    #map{
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:25%;
      width:75%
    }
    .top {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
       background:white;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding:100px 0"><h1>My title</h1></div>
    <div style="position:relative;height:100%">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="heading font-body text-title-4 font-title text-primary1">
        <p>Hospitals</p>
        </div>
       <div id="listings" class="listings font-body"></div>
      </div>
      
    <div id="map" class="map pad2"></div> 
    <div class="top">
        <div class="map-overlay-inner">
            <nav id="nav-filter">
                 <fieldset>
                    <legend>Région</legend>
                    <div>
                        <input id="all" type="radio" name="radio" onclick="filterMarkers()"/>
                        <label for="all">All</label>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input id="region1" type="radio" name="radio" onclick="filterMarkers(this)"/>
                        <label for="region1">region 1</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input id="region2" type="radio" name="radio" onclick="filterMarkers(this)"/>
                        <label for="region2">region 2</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input id="region3" type="radio" name="radio" onclick="filterMarkers(this)"/>
                        <label for="region3">region 3</label>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </nav>
            
        </div>
    </div>      
    </div>
    <div style="padding:100px 0"><h2>My footer</h2></div>
<script>
  var map = new maplibregl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: {
      'version': 8,
      'sources': {
        'raster-tiles': {
          'type': 'raster',
          'tiles': [
            "https://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png",
            "https://b.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png",
            "https://c.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png",
            "https://d.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png"
          ],
          'tileSize': 256,
          'attribution':
          '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>'
        }
      },
       "glyphs": "https://fonts.openmaptiles.org/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
      'layers': [
        {
        'id': 'simple-tiles',
        'type': 'raster',
        'source': 'raster-tiles',
        'minzoom': 0,
        'maxzoom': 22
        }
      ]
    },
    center: [2.3514998, 48.85661], // starting position
    zoom: 5, // starting zoom
    cooperativeGestures: true
  });
    
   var stores = 
   {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
       {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          5.8600224,
          48.6805776
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "house 3",
        "region": "region 2",
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          6.099311399999999,
          48.6143564
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "house 2",
        "region": "region 2",
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          6.1611808,
          48.6718265
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "house1",
        "region": "region 2",
       
      }
    },
     {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.5193906,
          45.9452769
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "house 6",
        "region": "region 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -1.0026331,
          45.62014
        ]
      },
      "properties": {

        "name": "house 5",
        "region": "region 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          0.1955502,
          46.0287897
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "house 4",
        "region": "region 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          3.689009,
          43.4474489
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "house 9",
        "region": "region 3"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          3.9077075,
          43.62659379999999
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "house 8",
        "region": "region 3"
      }
    },


    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          3.8874525,
          43.5972365
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "house 7",
        "region": "region 3"
      }
    }
      ]
  };
  
  stores.features.forEach((store, i) => {
    store.properties.id = i;
  });

  function getLabel(id) {
    return $("#"+id).next("label").html();
  }
  
  var regions = {};
  
  const regionCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
  regionCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
    const region = getLabel(checkbox.id);
    if (region != 'All') {
      var filteredFeatures = stores.features.filter(feature => (feature.properties.region == region));
      var bbox = turf.bbox(turf.featureCollection(filteredFeatures));
      
      regions[checkbox.id] = bbox;
    }
  });
         
  map.on('load', () => {
    map.addSource('stores', {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': stores,
      'cluster': true,
      'clusterMaxZoom': 14, // Max zoom to cluster points on
      'clusterRadius': 50
    });

    // addMarkers();
    map.addLayer({
      id: 'clusters',
      type: 'circle',
      source: 'stores',
      filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
      paint: {
        'circle-color': [
          'step',
          ['get', 'point_count'],
          '#525CA3',
          100,
          '#525CA3',
          750,
          '#525CA3'
        ],
        'circle-radius': [
          'step',
          ['get', 'point_count'],
          20,
          100,
          30,
          750,
          40
        ]
      }
    });

    map.addLayer({
      id: 'cluster-count',
      type: 'symbol',
      source: 'stores',
      filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
      layout: {
        'text-field': '{point_count_abbreviated}',
        'text-font': ['Open Sans Bold'],
       
        'text-size': 12,
        "icon-image": "{marker-symbol}",
        "icon-size": 0.20
      },
      paint: {
        "text-color": "#ffffff"
      }
    });


    map.addLayer({
      id: 'unclustered-point',
      type: 'circle',
      source: 'stores',
      filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
      paint: {
        'circle-color': '#525CA3',
        'circle-radius': 15,
        'circle-stroke-width': 1,
        'circle-stroke-color': '#fff'
      }
    });

    buildLocationList(stores); 

    map.on('click', 'clusters', (e) => {
      const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
        layers: ['clusters']
      });
      const clusterId = features[0].properties.cluster_id;
      map.getSource('stores').getClusterExpansionZoom(
        clusterId,
        (err, zoom) => {
          if (err) return;            
          map.easeTo({
            center: features[0].geometry.coordinates,
            zoom: zoom
          });
        }
      );
    });

    map.on('click', 'unclustered-point', (e) => {
      const coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
      const region = e.features[0].properties.region;
      const name = e.features[0].properties.name;
      
      while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
        coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
      }
       
      for (const marker of stores.features) {
        const activeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
        if (activeItem[0]) {
          activeItem[0].classList.remove('active');
        }
        const listing = document.getElementById(
          `listing-${e.features[0].properties.id}`
        );
        listing.classList.add('active');
        listing.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'start' });
      };
      
      new maplibregl.Popup({ closeOnClick: true })
      .setLngLat(coordinates)
      .setHTML(`<h3>${listing.properties.name}</h3><h4>${listing.properties.region}</h4>`)
      .addTo(map);
    });
               
    map.on('mouseenter', 'clusters', () => {
      map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
    map.on('mouseleave', 'clusters', () => {
      map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
    });
  });
    
      
  function buildLocationList(stores) {
    for (const store of stores.features) {
      const listings = document.getElementById('listings');
      const listing = listings.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      listing.id = `listing-${store.properties.id}`;
      listing.className = 'item';
      const link = listing.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
      link.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
      link.className = 'title';
      link.id = `link-${store.properties.id}`;
      link.innerHTML = `<h3 style="margin:0 0 10px">${store.properties.name}</h3>`;
      const details = listing.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    
      if(store.properties.region) {
        details.innerHTML +=  `<p style="margin:0">${store.properties.region }</p>`
      }
      link.addEventListener('click', function () {
        for (const feature of stores.features) {
          if (this.id === `link-${feature.properties.id}`) {
            flyToStore(feature);
            createPopUp(feature);
          }
        }
        const activeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
        if (activeItem[0]) {
          activeItem[0].classList.remove('active');
        }
          this.parentNode.classList.add('active');

      });
    }
  }  
  
  function flyToStore(currentFeature) {
    map.flyTo({
      center: currentFeature.geometry.coordinates,
      zoom: 15
    });
  }
  
  function createPopUp(currentFeature) {        
    const popUps = document.getElementsByClassName('maplibregl-popup');
    if (popUps[0]) popUps[0].remove();
    const popup = new maplibregl.Popup({ closeOnClick: true })
      .setLngLat(currentFeature.geometry.coordinates)
      .setHTML(
        `'<h3>${currentFeature.properties.name}</h3><h4>${currentFeature.properties.region}</h4>`
      )  
      .addTo(map);   
  }           
  
  const nav = new maplibregl.NavigationControl({
    visualizePitch: true
  });
  map.addControl(nav, 'bottom-right');
    
  function getSelectedRegions() {
    const selectedRegions = [];
    const regionCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked');
    regionCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => selectedRegions.push(getLabel(checkbox.id)));
    return selectedRegions;
  }
   
  function filterMarkers(button) {
    const selectedRegions = getSelectedRegions();
    const mapSource = map.getSource('stores');
    if (selectedRegions[0] == 'All') {
      setAllMarkersVisible(mapSource);
      return;
    }
    const filteredFeatures = stores.features.filter(feature => selectedRegions.includes(feature.properties.region));
    mapSource.setData({
      ...stores,
      features: filteredFeatures
    });
    map.fitBounds(regions[button.id],  {
      padding: {top: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50, right: 50}
    });
  }
   
  function setAllMarkersVisible(mapSource) {
    mapSource.setData(stores);
    map.flyTo({
      center: [2.3514998, 48.85661], // starting position
      zoom: 5, // starting zoom
    });
  }
</script>
 
</body>
</html>




What exactly do you mean by "the list makes the page jump"?

My actual map is like the example provided. If I display the map alone in full screen, like on the Mapbox example, no problem. As long as I add blocks at the top and bottom of the map, when I click on one of the items in the list, the page repositions itself either at the top or at the bottom. This is a problem usually solved by a preventDefault() or javascript:void, but here I have the impression that it has to do with the html code. I look hard I can't find it. In the example provided, when you click on an item in the list (to the left of the card) the page jumps upwards.

First about when you just put <h3>${name}</h3><h4>${region}</h4> then the page doesn't jump anymore. Of course not, since jump is consequence of focus being set to created popup, but in this case popup is not created because of an error. If you look at the browse debugger console, you will see

Uncaught ReferenceError: region is not defined

To prevent focus being set to created popup and as a consequence window jump, option focusAfterOpen: false has to be used when creating popup:
const popup = new maplibregl.Popup({closeOnClick: true, focusAfterOpen: false})
  .setLngLat(currentFeature.geometry.coordinates)
  .setHTML(
    `<h3>${currentFeature.properties.name}</h3><h4>${currentFeature.properties.region}</h4>`
  )  
  .addTo(map);


waouh it's working...didn't know about that ! thanks a lot  (again ^^)
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/10329
